# jQuery not recognizing div id

Tags: jquery

Something really weird is happening to my Rails app.

For some strange reason, jQuery does not recognise my id's in the DOM.
Let me give you an example.

I have a JavaScript function as shown below:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        $('#hello').toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Simple enough, it should toggle the element with the id="hello".
But it gives me a `$("#hello")` is null error. (Even though there is one in the view file)

But if I use `$('hello').toggle()` instead of `$('#hello').toggle()`, the expected behavior is observed.

Can somebody please tell me what is happening?

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: it is a good ideia you show us your html once it is probally that you have more then one div with the same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you (or some component) is adding the Prototype library to your page? In Prototype, you select by ID using $('id') rather than $('#id'). Also, Prototype's $() function will return null if it doesn't find a match, while jQuery's $() function will never return null.

If Prototype (or another library with a $() function) is being loaded after jQuery, it would stomp all over jQuery's version of the $() function.

If it turns out this is the case, and you can't avoid using both jQuery and the other library, you'll probably want to take advantage of [jQuery.noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict).

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same experience and was losing my mind!  But I realized that I had duplicated a previous HTML page to maintain the same format but it copied the IDs over to the new page, so jQuery got confused on which ID it was.

*Remember to make your IDs unique **throughout the site**.*

Six years late, but I hope this post helps others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have that script after the html has loaded?

If not, put it inside this tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

The script could probably be executing before the HTML has loaded, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The `$('hello')` selector matches on an element with a name of hello, `$('#hello')` would match on an element with an id of hello.  Could you have mistakenly named the element instead of applying the id?

Answer (score 0):

In my weird case I had two ids in one id-field of an element like: p id="id1 id2" ... and even if you try to access the right id jQuery("#id1")... this error comes up, that the object is undefined. cheers!

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: As I understand it, it is about why jQuery probably does not recognize a given and existing id. If a moderator thinks, that my answer is not a usefull information on the search for possible mistakes, then delete my input. No probs. Thank you